# Showing only one solution, 'deactivating' the other solution

Tags: javascript

I tried to write a script that shows two different texts (`div`s) depending on which of two `<p>` elements is clicked. The `<div>`s show up on click, but after clicking one, the other one should be 'deactivated' using the variable `fin_var`. 
The deactivation using `fin_var = false;` doesn't work.

If I click the second `<p>` after the first one, also the second `<div>` appears. Help would be very much appreciated!

Here are the code:

```js
var fin_var = true;

var sen_one = document.getElementById('sentence_one');
if (fin_var == true) {
  sen_one.addEventListener('click', function() {
     // show div1
    fin_var = false;
  }, false);
}
var sen_two = document.getElementById('sentence_two');
if (fin_var == true) {
  sen_two.addEventListener('click', function() {
    // show div2
    fin_var = false;
  }, false);
}
```

```html
<p id="sentence_one">Solution 1</p>
<p id="sentence_two">Solution 2</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because all code inside the `addEventListener` callback function will be executed only when the user clicks, so when you are setting the callbacks the `fin_var` are true. It becomes false only when one element is clicked, but then the callback click functions are already defined.

Here's what you should do instead:

```js
var fin_var = true;

var sen_one = document.getElementById('sentence_one');
sen_one.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (fin_var) { //it's the same as fin_var == true, for your purposes
    // show div1
    fin_var = false;
  }
}, false);

var sen_two = document.getElementById('sentence_two');
sen_two.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (fin_var) {
    // show div2
    fin_var = false;
  }
}, false);
```

```html
<p id="sentence_one">Solution 1</p>
<p id="sentence_two">Solution 2</p>
```

This way the callback function is always defined, but it does nothing when the control variable is set to false.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some solution, click on "Run code snippet" on the bottom for the working demo

It works by declaring which **div** should each **p** show while hiding all the others

The advantage of this approach is that it doesn't matter if you use it on `<p>, <div>, etc...` to show/hide whatever, and it works for any number of "buttons" and "showables"

Also, ignoring the cosmetic CSS (which isn't part of the solution) its even less code than both the original question and the accepted answer and avoids duplication :D

```js
document
  .querySelectorAll('[toggle]')
  .forEach((toggle) => toggle.addEventListener('click', toggles))
  
function toggles () {
  var shouldShow = this.getAttribute('toggle')
  
  document.querySelectorAll('.toggleable').forEach((toggleable) => {
    var toggleId = toggleable.getAttribute('id')
    
    toggleable.classList[(toggleId == shouldShow)? "remove" : "add"]('hidden')
  })
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none
}

/* CSS after this comment NOT NEEDED */
#sentence_one, #div_one {
  background-color: pink
}

#sentence_two, #div_two {
  background-color: lightblue
}

[toggle] { cursor: pointer }

[toggle], .toggleable {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: darkgray;
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<p id="sentence_one" toggle="div_one">Solution 1 ~ click to show div 1</p>
<p id="sentence_two" toggle="div_two">Solution 2 ~ click to show div 2</p>

<hr>

<div id="div_one" class="toggleable">div 1</div>
<div id="div_two" class="toggleable hidden">div 2</div>
```